# How can I search for a user account in various sudo related config files?

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I would like to search multiple servers for user `ss7459` in the following files `/etc/sudoers`, `/etc/sudoers.d/itse`, `/etc/sudoers.d/dbas` and `/etc/group`.

**NOTE:** The numbers after the `ss` may not be constant across all the servers... on some it may be `ss3945...` and so on but it all starts with `ss`.

Can someone please help me write a script for this?

Also, I'll be running this on a satellite with all servers on it thus the main aim is to find out all the servers with that user (ss7***) on them. I'll also be needing a way to get the servers name and compile a list of those servers.

Comment: For the “search multiple servers” part, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19008/automatically-run-commands-over-ssh-on-many-servers

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
grep -P 'ss\d+' /etc/group /etc/sudoers.d/dbas  /etc/sudoers.d/itse /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: awesome...it worked, thanks Babyy...is there a way i can find out all servers with that user(ss7***) on them...cos i'll also be needing a way to get the servers name and compile a list of those servers... i'll eventually post that script on a satellite server

Comment: You'll have to run this command on each of the servers individually. You could make use of `ssh` and run the above command through `ssh` looping through a list of servers too.