# ssh command with quotes

Tags: shell, ssh, quoting

I have an odd error that I have been unable to find anything on this. I wanted to change the user comment with the following command.

```
$ sudo usermod -c "New Comment" user
```

This will work while logged onto a server but I want to automate it across 20+ servers. Usually I am able to use a list and loop through the servers and run a command but in this case I get a error.

```
$ for i in `cat servlist` ; do echo $i ; ssh $i sudo usermod -c "New Comment" user ; done 
serv1
Usage: usermod [options] LOGIN

Options:
lists usermod options

serv2
Usage: usermod [options] LOGIN

Options:
lists usermod options
.
.
.
```

When I run this loop it throws back an error like I am using the command incorrectly but it will run just fine on a single server.

Looking through the ssh man pages I did try `-t` and `-t -t` flags but those did not work.

I have successfully used `perl -p -i -e` within a similar loop to edit files.

Does anyone know a reason I am unable to loop this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for i in `cat servlist`;do echo $i;ssh $i 'sudo usermod -c "New Comment" user';done
```

or

```
for i in `cat servlist`;do echo $i;ssh $i "sudo usermod -c \"New Comment\" user";done
```

Answer (score 38):

SSH executes the remote command in a shell. It passes a string to the remote shell, not a list of arguments. The arguments that you pass to the `ssh` commands are concatenated with spaces in between. The arguments to `ssh` are `sudo`, `usermod`, `-c`, `New Comment` and `user`, so the remote shell sees the command

```
sudo usermod -c New Comment user
```

`usermod` parses `Comment` as the name of the user and `user` as a spurious extra parameter.

You need to pass the quotes to the remote shell so that the comment is treated as a string. The simplest way is to put the whole remote command in single quotes. If you need a single quote in that command, use `'\''`.

```
ssh "$i" 'sudo usermod -c "Jack O'\''Brian" user'
```

Instead of calling `ssh` in a loop and ignoring errors, use a tool designed to run commands on multiple servers such as pssh, mussh, clusterssh, etc. See [Automatically run commands over SSH on many servers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19008/automatically-run-commands-over-ssh-on-many-servers)

Comment: Another good tool is Ansible for running commands on multiple servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following convenient wrapper script `ssh.sh`

EDIT 2023/04/28. Finally I figure out the perfect solution, fixed the issue mentioned by @user202729, yet not over-programing.

The final ssh wrapper is:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=(); for v in "$@"; do args+=("$(printf %q "$v")"); done
ssh "${args[@]}"
```

You can create it by copy&paste run:

```
cat <<'EOF' > ssh.sh
#!/bin/bash
args=(); for v in "$@"; do args+=("$(printf %q "$v")"); done
ssh "${args[@]}"
EOF

chmod +x ssh.sh
```

Then you can safely call ssh via the `ssh.sh`, without worrying about escaping.

```
./ssh.sh host sudo usermod -c "New Comment" user
```

A full test:

First create a utility /tmp/show_args.sh which shows all arguments

```
cat <<'EOF' > /tmp/show_args.sh
#!/bin/bash
for arg in "$@"; do echo "ARG$((++i))=${arg@Q}"; done
EOF

chmod +x /tmp/show_args.sh
```

The do the full test:

```
./ssh.sh 127.0.0.1 -n /tmp/show_args.sh "a a" "'b b'" '"c c"' '*' '()' $'line1\nline2' $'\001    a' 'zz   '
```

The output is:

```
ARG1='a a'
ARG2=''\''b b'\'''
ARG3='"c c"'
ARG4='*'
ARG5='()'
ARG6=$'line1\nline2'
ARG7=$'\001    a'
ARG8='zz   '
```

You can see that all arguments are same as the input.
Note

```
''\''b b'\'''
```

just means literal

```
'b b'
```

Comment: This will give wrong result if the output of `%q` contains two consecutive spaces e.g. it happens for `echo $'\x01  12  3'`  in my bash version

Comment: oh sorry to here that. Maybe it is because of bash version. Could you test it with following command? I have tried it, no problem.  `./ssh.sh host echo $'\x01  12  3' | od -txCc`, then check the binary output, it should be `01  20  31  32  20  33  0a`.

Comment: But `echo $'\x01  12  3'` executed locally is 01 20 20 31 32 20 20 33 0a, and your theory is it will be the same remotely, but it's not, because command substitution `$( )` breaks at whitespace -- even if it occurs between quotemarks, unlike shell input. This applies to all bash versions (although very old versions don't have %q and never reach the point of error). More dramatically, try `ssh.sh host echo $'\x07 * * * IMPORTANT * * *'`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 nice catch, thanks for telling me this, I will find a workaround.

Comment: @user202729,  thanks for letting me know this issue. I have updated my answer, added some test cases and a workaround for this issue at the end.

Comment: No need, overcomplicated. Just change `ssh $(escape "$@")
` to `ssh "$(escape "$@")"
` in the first script (didn't test but should work.

Comment: @user202729 yes, I have first tried that, but that breaks other things, it will treat the `ssh host cmd args` to `ssh 'host cmd args'`, so it did not work. That's why I split the scripts.

Comment: Updated my answer, improved to a perfect solution, yet not over-programming.