# sed + remove string on remote machine

Tags: linux, ssh, sed

please advice what is wrong with my sed syntax ?

```
ssh postgres@172.34.5.76 sed -i '/archive_command/ s/#BARMAN#[ ]*//g'  /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf"

sed: -e expression #1, char 17: missing command
```

my target is to remove the #BARMAN# string on remote machine

when I do this on local machine its works as the following:

```
sed -i '/archive_command/ s/#BARMAN#[ ]*//g'  /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf"
```

Comment: I think there's a Q or A on here that covers this better; but you need another level of quoting to pass it through `ssh`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4770/quoting-in-ssh-host-foo-and-ssh-host-sudo-su-user-c-foo-type-constructs

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212298/117549

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is wrong.

It has to be :

```
ssh postgres@host 'sed -i "/archive_command/ s/#BARMAN#[ ]*//g"  /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf"'
```

You forgot the quotes before and after the command. And added double quotes instead of single quotes so that there is no need to escape it.

Comment: Careful - there are single-quotes as part of the sed command, which will leave them exposed to splitting.

Comment: Updated my answer to escape the quotes. @JeffSchaller Edit if I made a mistake. I am not sure if the escaping is done right.

Comment: Since there are no double-quotes or variables in the listed command, wrapping it with double quotes would work for this particular Q.

Comment: Updated with double quotes. @yael I might not know `sed` too well, So I ask, is this the right syntax? `/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf"` With only a single double quote at the end of `.conf` ?