# why does sh -c over ssh discards the first command

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

`sh -c 'echo hello ; echo world'`
Works fine on both host and remote machine, with the output of:

```
hello
world
```

but when I do
`ssh username@remote sh -c 'echo hello ; echo world'`, then the output is:

```
world
```

Why did the command eat my first `echo hello` command?

Comment: [Gilles's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212298/70524) describes what's happening: by the time the remote shell runs it, it looks like `sh -c echo hello; echo world`, `sh -c echo hello` runs `echo` without arguments (`hello` is `$0` for `sh -c`), and `echo world`, so you get the empty line and `world`.