# sed & ssh ./hostsallow.sh: line 11: sed -i /deployit$/a: No such file or directory

Tags: ssh, sed

I'm trying to add an ip adress on a list of hosts.

when I do this directly on the host it works:

```
sed i- /apache$/a sshd: 192.168.2.2 : allow' /etc/hosts.allow
```

But when I do this by script bash it writes in log.txt file:

```
./hostsallow.sh: line 11: sed -i /apache$/a: No such file or directory
```

here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

for q in `cat itg4`
do

echo $q &>> log.txt


ssh $q -n 'sed -i '/apache$/a sshd: 192.168.2.2 : allow' /etc/hosts.allow' &>> log.txt
done
```

the set -x gives on screen:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

Please can you help me?

Best regards,

Comment: Related: [ssh command with quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212215/ssh-command-with-quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the issue

```
ssh $q "sed -i '/apache$/a sshd: 192.168.2.2 : allow' /etc/hosts.allow" &>> log.txt
```