# List all the processes running on Linux cluster servers

Tags: linux, cluster

I am running GNU/Linux EDT 2012, it has 11 cluster servers, is there a way besides remote sign on to find out processes running on all the 11 servers at once? I tried running ps command on one of the servers but it lists down the PIDs for processes which are running on that particular server only and not of all the 11 servers.

Comment: "EDT 2012" is not a Linux distribution that I am aware of.  Are you sure that's the name of the OS you're running?

Comment: Do you know what cluster management software (e.g., torque/maui/pbs) this cluster is running?

Comment: its a linux version, sorry no, I am not aware of them

Comment: Without more detailed information, it's going to be difficult to get a good answer to your question.  Running `ps` on each server individually is likely the best solution we can give you unless you have more information about the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

An idea could be to run ssh commands in parallel on all computers. See second answer this with tools for this:

[Automatically run commands over SSH on many servers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19008/automatically-run-commands-over-ssh-on-many-servers)