# Free text search for bash commands

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

I have 5 servers to manage (ssh, tunnel, etc). So is there a way/plugin to perform a free text search and execute a command. For example I map a sentence to a bash command and filter in terminal via free text search. I know about history search with ctrl + R command but its a bit cumbersome to search through all ips to find the relevant server.

For Example

```
Text : "ssh to server 1" >> "ssh nirojan@ipaddress"
Text : "tunnel to server 5" "ssh -L 5234:localhost:5433 "
```

Comment: Use more hostnames?

Comment: Yes that's also a possibility ! I was also wondering whether any tool or plugin exist for this kind of operation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your shell supports aliases (see comments section), you could use aliases:

```
alias sshserv1='ssh root@5.8.66.33'
alias sshserv2='ssh root@1.4.6.8'
```

You would put these in your `~/.bashrc` for example.

More info here:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html

Alternatively: the brilliant `hstr` tool (here: https://github.com/dvorka/hstr) is a great command history searcher and beats Ctrl+R on all fronts.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the hstr tool, this is pretty cool.

Comment: Note that aliases come from csh and are also found in all Korn-like shells, not only bash. In Bourne-like and rc-like shells, you can use functions instead. In any shell, you can use scripts.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thank you for pointing that out. Edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 4):

#### For SSH specifically

Define host aliases in your SSH client configuration file [`~/.ssh/config`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5). For example:

```
Host server1
    Hostname ipaddress
    User nirojan

Host server5-tunnel
    Hostname server5
    LocalForward 5234:localhost:5433
```

Then `ssh server1` is equivalent to `nirojan@ipaddress`, and so on. The advantage of this method is that it works with everything that uses SSH under the hood, for example `rsync -a somefile server1:some/directory`.

If you've enabled context-sensitive completion on bash or zsh, the shell will complete host aliases where you can use them with commands like `ssh`, `sftp`, `rsync`, etc.

Also, if you need to do the same thing on multiple servers, see [Automatically run commands over SSH on many servers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19008/automatically-run-commands-over-ssh-on-many-servers)